# How to get values from the sliderInput and write them to a variable?

Tags: r, shiny

Here is the part of the code:

**ui.r**

```
sidebarPanel(
   sliderInput("days", "Analyzing days", min = 22, max = 132, value = 25)),
```

**server.r**

```
var<-input$days
```

As a result, the console gives an error:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

and the application closes automatically.
I need to assign a value to the **sliderInput** variable, so I can then manipulate it differently.
***How can I do it?***

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the variable inside something that can deal with the user changing the value, this is called a reactive environment. You can use `reactive()` or something like `observeEvent()` as I have done here to achieve this.

```
server<-function(input,output){

var = NULL

# Turns variable into reactive variable.
makeReactiveBinding("var")

# Make reactive environment and assign variable based on value
observeEvent(input$days, { 
var<<-input$days
})

} #close server
```

credit: [How to plot selected input from selectInput() function in shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726365/how-to-plot-selected-input-from-selectinput-function-in-shiny/50726473#50726473) @Scrappy

Comment: Yes that works, but there is an error. `sliderInput` has `max=132`. If I use `observeEvent` and in the application I set the value from `50` to `82` it closes automatically and gives an error: _Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed_. At other values ​​of a `sliderInput` all works normally. In the script I have "if", but it does not have either 50 or 82.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the code, we can only guess. If thats the only code, its clearly not gonna work ;)

Maybe this little example can illustrate you some basics:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("days", "Analyzing days", min = 22, max = 132, value = 25),
  verbatimTextOutput("slidInp")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$slidInp <- renderPrint({
    var <- input$days

    var2 <- c(1:as.numeric(var))

    print(var2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I need some like that: 
`var1<-input$days`
`var2<-c(1:var)`

Comment: Yes. Thank you!